# Unprotected connection to HTTPS web-page

Tags: tls, web-browser, openssl

A couple of days ago we noticed that when we go to our online banking login page (using Opera browser as usual) there is no green lock icon there anymore. Instead, there is a grey globe icon which states "unprotected connection" even though it is an HTTPS page.

We also tried using Chrome - same problem. We have checked this problem on two different machines (Windows 7, Windows 8, Ubuntu and mac). Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be and how we could fix it? Is it a problem with the website or with our machines? 
[image]

Comment: Well, what does it say when you click on "Details"? There should be more information...

Comment: it showing first visited, connection, certificates, errors : "this page contains insecure content" @MarcSchütz

Comment: That'll do it - some image or script on the page being loaded over HTTP will mark the whole page as insecure since updates recently to browsers. The site owner needs to fix it, rather than the end user though.

Comment: yes, now I got the issue @Matthew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome displays a mixed content warning. Google has a good article outlining how to prevent this. [Preventing Mixed Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uP59.jpg). This is likely to protect against prior harm XSS has caused. Particularly when XSS is performed on a website without HTTP. Although, I cannot see how this would be a problem.[image]

Mozilla Firefox displays the connection as secure without any security warnings.

Although, Opera seems to display the connection as "Unprotected connection" when the mixed content warning is given.[image]
It can be seen that a secure HTTPS connection is established with a valid certificate and TLS 1.2, etc...

SSL Labs analysis shows yourdomain.com uses HSTS.

> Is it a problem with the website or with our machines?

As you can see from the results above, this is not an issue with the client-side, as Opera is designed to respond like this. Instead, it's an issue with the server-side, where the developer did not consider all browsers and how they would respond.